# Replacing the login e-mail address doesn't replace the notification e-mail address

Tags: discussion, bug, login, email, email-notification

A few days ago, I changed the e-mail address associated with my Stack Exchange account by adding the new e-mail address, then deleting the old one and deleting the old address from the mail service. This worked fine.

However, I noticed that I stopped receiving e-mail notifications for inbox messages, including chat pings, comments and comment pings.

Looking through my profile, I see that while *My Logins* lists only the new e-mail address used for login purposes, *Edit Email Settings* still shows the old address.

This might perhaps be intended behavior, but I find it rather surprising. The principle of least surprise would seem to me to suggest that at least, when deleting a login with the e-mail address associated with notifications, the user should be told that they also need to update the e-mail address under *Edit Email Settings* as presumably they intend to change the address associated with their account.

Can/should something be done about this?